# How to Address Factor Values with Quotations in R

Tags: r

I'll appreciate if someone can describe this to me! My mind is about to blow up on this fundamental logical inconsistency!

```
> class(trlog$X.sce_status.[1])
[1] "factor"
> trlog$X.sce_status.[1]
[1] "Successful"
Levels: "Failed-CMD INF ERROR" "Failed-TRANS EXPIRED" "Successful"
> trlog$X.sce_status.[1] == as.character("Successful")
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: Just wondering, what is the result of `as.character(trlog$X.sce_status.[1])`?

Comment: Please provide the output of `charToRaw(as.character(trlog$X.sce_status.[1]))`

Comment: > charToRaw(as.character(trlog$X.sce_status.[1]))
 [1] 22 53 75 63 63 65 73 73 66 75 6c 22

Comment: @EliSadoff I think you're right on the point. > as.character(trlog$X.sce_status.[1])
[1] "\"Successful\""

Comment: `charToRaw(as.character("Successful"))` gives `53 75 63 63 65 73 73 66 75 6c`

Comment: However: > trlog$X.sce_status.[1]
[1] "Successful"
Levels: "Failed-CMD INF ERROR" "Failed-TRANS EXPIRED" "Successful"
> trlog$X.sce_status.[1] == as.character("Successful")
[1] FALSE

Comment: Well there's your logical inconsistency. They're not actually the same, they just appear to be the same, so R, correctly, says they are different.

Comment: and how do you describe above? i.e. > trlog$X.sce_status.[1]
[1] "Successful"
Levels: "Failed-CMD INF ERROR" "Failed-TRANS EXPIRED" "Successful"
> trlog$X.sce_status.[1] == as.character("Successful")
[1] FALSE

Comment: I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Your factor is literally `"Successful"`, note the quotes. This will work: 
`trlog$X.sce_status.[1] == as.character("\"Successful\"")`

Comment: Thank you guys! It worked. I'm going to post a short answer for future reference.

Comment: I deleted the answer, please feel free to add.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key to the confusion here is the way that R prints out elements of a `factor` variable.  If you construct a simple factor variable:

```
f <- factor("Successful")
```

and print it

```
f[1]
## [1] Successful
## Levels: Successful
```

you can see that R prints out the level name **without quotation marks**.  On the other hand, if you have a (slightly weird) factor where the labels *actually contain quotation marks*, you get a reasonable-seeming but subtly different result printed:

```
g <- factor("\"Successful\"")
g
## [1] "Successful"
## Levels: "Successful"
```

This becomes a little bit clearer (?) if you print the results of `as.character`, which *does* print with quotation marks by default:

```
as.character(f)
## [1] "Successful"
as.character(g)
## [1] "\"Successful\""
```

You can use `print(as.character(g),quote=FALSE)` or `print(g,quote=TRUE)` if you want to add/subtract quotation marks from the printed representation.